# made a hard sql request to find the count of likes for a picture

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've 3 tables in my databases :

user, pic, like made with :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    `email` varchar(255), 
    `login` varchar(255), 
    `password` varchar(255), 
    `admin` boolean,
    `pwreset` boolean,
    `validate_link` varchar(255),
    `created_at` date, PRIMARY KEY( `id` )
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pic` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255),
    `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` date,
    PRIMARY KEY( `id` )
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `like` (
    `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `pic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `created_at` date,
    PRIMARY KEY( `id` )
);";
```

I tried to fetch my pics and get the login through the owner_id of pic

I made this :

```
$find_pic = $db->prepare("SELECT p.*, u.login FROM camagru_jgengo.pic as p INNER JOIN camagru_jgengo.user as u ON p.owner_id = u.id  ORDER BY p.id DESC ");
$find_pic->execute();
$pics = $find_pic->fetchAll();
```

the output is :

```
[0] => Array
(
    [id] => 189
    [0] => 189
    [name] => 1492882407.png
    [1] => 1492882407.png
    [owner_id] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [created_at] => 2017-04-22
    [3] => 2017-04-22
    [login] => jgengo
    [4] => jgengo
)

...
```

Now , I would like to have a new information in this array, something like :

`$pics[x][likes_count]` which is the number of likes found with the `like.pic_id` with this `pic.id`

I tried it :

```
$find_pic = $db->prepare("SELECT p.*, u.login, l.like FROM camagru_jgengo.pic as p INNER JOIN camagru_jgengo.user as u ON p.owner_id = u.id INNER JOIN camagru_jgengo.like as  l.pic_id = p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC ");
$find_pic->execute();
$pics = $find_pic->fetchAll();
```

But It doesn't work, could someone helps me please ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what exactly? Is there an error message?

Comment: Format your queries with line breaks. This way finding syntax errors wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: If I write this :
`$find_pic = $db->prepare("SELECT p.*, u.login, l.owner_id FROM camagru_jgengo.pic as p INNER JOIN camagru_jgengo.user as u ON p.owner_id = u.id INNER JOIN camagru_jgengo.like as l ON l.pic_id = p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC");`

$find_pic is empty

Answer (score 2):

This query is wrong

```
SELECT 
    p.*, u.login, l.like 
FROM 
    camagru_jgengo.pic as p 
INNER JOIN 
    camagru_jgengo.user as u ON p.owner_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN 
    camagru_jgengo.like as  l.pic_id = p.id 
ORDER BY 
    p.id DESC
```

`l.pic_id` you haven't defined what is `l`

So it should be corrected as

```
SELECT 
    p.*, u.login, l.like 
FROM 
    camagru_jgengo.pic as p 
INNER JOIN 
    camagru_jgengo.user as u ON p.owner_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN 
    camagru_jgengo.like as l ON l.pic_id = p.id 
ORDER BY 
    p.id DESC
```

Comment: I tried it :
`$find_pic = $db->prepare("SELECT p.*, u.login, l.owner_id FROM camagru_jgengo.pic as p INNER JOIN camagru_jgengo.user as u ON p.owner_id = u.id INNER JOIN camagru_jgengo.like as l ON l.pic_id = p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC");`

but it fetch nothing. my array is empty.

Comment: Did you try the query directly on a mysql client? what does it return there?

Comment: `mysql> SELECT p.*, u.login, l.owner_id FROM camagru_jgengo.pic as p INNER JOIN camagru_jgengo.user as u ON p.owner_id = u.id INNER JOIN camagru_jgengo.like as l ON l.pic_id = p.id ORDER BY p.id DESC;`
Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Are you sure whether there are any matching records for `like` table and `pic` table. `INNER JOIN` will return only the matching records.

Answer (score 0):

I succeed with :

```
SELECT p.*, u.login, count(l.pic_id) as likes
FROM camagru_jgengo.pic as p
LEFT JOIN camagru_jgengo.user as u ON p.owner_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN camagru_jgengo.like as l ON l.pic_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY p.id DESC;
```

Thank you everybody !